# How to execute script after container is just running

Tags: apache, docker

I'm using a docker container of apache.
I have to execute a script after the container is started. 
How can I do this?

First of all, I have a dockerfile:

```
FROM:ubunty:trusty
... necessary installs

ADD test.sh /my-folder/    

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

CMD ["/run.sh"]
```

In `run.sh` I'm executing as the last command: `exec apache2 -D FOREGROUND`, and this works.
Now I want an additional script `test.sh` to be be executed after the container is started.

In details, what I want is, after the apache container is started (this works), an additional script to be executed. That script has to connect to port 80 of my server (the port has been mapped at the run command).

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                      NAMES
61c66c17d5f1        my-apache            "/run.sh"           28 minutes ago      Up 28 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   suspicious_shockley
```

Comment: Can you run your script in another container instead?  What does it do that requires it to run in the same container?

Answer (score 0):

If you want manually run the script use:

```
docker exec 61c66c17d5f1 /myfolder/test.sh
```

If you want your script be executed automatically after apache starts modify your run.sh:

```
exec apache2 &
sleep 2
/myfolder/test.sh
wait
```

Regards

Comment: I want it using the automatic way. But that does not word. it seems that everything after the exec command isn't executed.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to implement this - create separate container for your application. It will also inherit your trusty image, but nothing else in it. It will execute all your stuff and exit with zero code. In this case you will not touch your apache service. You should map this container to your data volume as follows:

```
app:
    build: ./app/
    depends_on:
      - apache
    volumes:
      - /path/to/app:/var/www/html
```

As you said you want your script to be executed after apache starts. You can simply add field `depends_on` telling docker_compose to start it after apache service. But for this you should use docker notation V2.

By the way - in your case you need started apache service to connect from your script. You should replace `depends_on` with `links` - it will add apache IP to app container hosts file, so you can ping it with apache hostname.